# WebExtensions: How to send a message to content script? (Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

I just noticed that the tabs API is [only available for the desktop](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/#tabs) not for Android. In the past I have used this code to send messages to my content scripts:

```
sendMsgToTabs(msg) {
    return browser.tabs.query({}).then(tabs => {
        let msgPromises = []
        for (let tab of tabs) {
            let msgPromise = browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg)
            msgPromises.push(msgPromise)
        }
        return Promise.all(msgPromises)
    })
}
```

But how am I supposed to do that when the tabs API is not available?
I mean the only thing I can think of is to constantly send empty messages from the content scripts to the background script and whenever the background script has new information then it can send a direct response to one of these messages. But that sounds horribly inefficient. There must be a better way, right?

Comment: You could open a channel between pages and the background page using `browser.runtime.connect` in the content script and `browser.runtime.onConnect` in the background script. Store the ports in a list, and remove it from the list when the `port.onDisconnect` event fires.

Answer (score 2):

### As of Firefox 54, use [`.tabs.sendMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage)

As of Firefox 54, the [`tabs` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) [is supported on Firefox for Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs#Browser_compatibility).

### Alternative for versions of Firefox prior to Firefox 54.

The [`storage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage#Browser_compatibility) is stated as supported in Firefox for Android. Thus, while I have not tested it, a method you could use to send data to content script would be to save a value using [`chrome.storage.local.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set). By listening to the [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/onChanged) event in your content script(s), you can then be notified of that data being stored/changed. This will provide an event driven way to send a message (i.e. stored data) to the content script.

In order to differentiate between receiving the data in different tabs, you will need to establish a protocol for what the data you save means. This could be as simple as just a particular saved key/value meaning that all content scripts should send a message to the background script to get more information, or more complex where you send/store something like:

```
{
    contentScriptMessage: {
        tab: 14,
        frame: 1234,
        message: 'Some data'
    }
}
```

In each content script's [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/onChanged) listener, it can then ignore any changes that are not to the tab/frame in which it is running.

This methodology will require fleshing out as you try to implement it. Hopefully, at least part of the `chrome.tabs` API will be implemented for Android in the near future.